# Running minified in Grunt cannot read property of undefined

Tags: gruntjs, minify

I'm trying to build a Grunt task that minifys my JS files and return a single minified JS file.

This is my gruntfile.js file:

```
    module.exports = function (grunt) {

        // Project configuration.
        grunt.initConfig({
            minified: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                    'js/*.js',
                    ],
                    dest: 'js/min/'
                },
                options: {
                    allinone: true
                }
            },
        });

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-minified');
    };
```

When I run the task it does work, but it also returns an error.

```
    > cmd.exe /c grunt -b "C:\Users\alucardu\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JS-demo\JS-demo" --gruntfile "C:\Users\alucardu\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JS-demo\JS-demo\Gruntfile.js" minified
    Running "minified:files" (minified) task
    Warning: Cannot read property 'yellow' of undefined Use --force to continue.
    Process terminated with code 3.
    Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've done a search action in my entire solution for 'yellow' but it doesn't return any results. Also when I empty both my JS files that are being minified it still returns the error.

Does anyone know why it's returning this error?

Answer (score 0):

By removing the

```
options: {
  allinone: true
}
```

The warning no longer showed up, but it also doesn't concat the files together. So I've added another task called `concat`. So now my gruntfile looks like this:

```
    module.exports = function (grunt) {

        // Project configuration.
        grunt.initConfig({
            watch: {
                scripts: {
                    files: ['js/*.js'],
                    tasks: ['concat', 'minified', 'uglify'],
                },
            },
            concat: {
                dist: {
                    src: ['js/*.js'],
                    dest: 'js/min/concat.js'
                },
            },
            minified: {
                files: {
                    src: ['js/min/concat.js'],
                    dest: 'js/min/minified.js'
                },
            },
            uglify: {
                my_target: {
                    files: {
                        'js/min/uglify.js': ['js/min/minified.jsconcat.js']
                    }
                }
            },

        });

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-minified');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');


    };
```

And it seems to be working fine.